# How to create dynamic overlay panel in Axure?

Tags: wireframe, prototype

I would like to create a few dynamics panel like on [www.ted.com](http://www.ted.com/).

I have following problems:

- I would like to use one dynamic panel that will move on every image.
- I've created a `case` statement:

`OnMouseEnter`:

```
Bring `Panel1`to `Front`
Show `Panel1`
Move `Panel1` to 320,145
```

Moving cursor on panel causes blinking.

I would like do get rid of blinking effect.

- I would like also to create a condition that panel would disappear only when moving out of it.

Comment: This is off-topic here. How to use an app, even an app that UX experts use, belongs elsewhere (maybe on SuperUser)

Comment: I wouldn't agree. On `stackoverflow` there are plenty of questions about `Eclipse` usage and configuration. And they aren't flagged off-topic, mainly because `Eclipse` is tool used by programmers. Thus questions about `Axure` used by UX experts are also valid on this page IHMO.

Comment: Just because SO does some things a certain way doesn't mean that all of the SE sites should as well. Math.SE doesn't allow questions about how to use a calculator, does it? Precedent here is that specifics on how to use one tool or another are not on-topic here.

Comment: Sorry, You didn't convinced me :) There is no mention about not asking questions about tools closely related to UX in faq or meta. Apart from that, there are also quite few tool related question on this site: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5570/google-drawing-wireframing or http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/831/which-prototyping-tools . Should they also be flagged as off-topic?

Comment: I agree with @pixel that this is not necessarily off-topic for UX.SE, although we might not be able to give the best answers.  When a tool has its own forum, one is likely to get the best answers to the sort of question there, as I mentioned in my answer.  Still, I don't think this should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing exactly what you're trying to do (e.g. the RP file), it's hard to know exactly what's going wrong, but I would suspect it's a problem with OnMouseOut... generally, for complex dynamic panels, you need to create a [mouse-out "moat"](http://forum.axure.com/axure-rp-pro-faqs-ultimate-resources-thread/4372-axure-faq.html) as opposed to using the 'stock' MouseOut interaction.

However, for questions like these, it's probably best that you go to the [Axure forums](http://forum.axure.com/forum.php), and ask it there.  The folks there know this tool inside and out, so they're be able to give you a better answer than the general UX.SE community.